# Set scroll y for md-tab-body div using AngularJS matrial

Tags: html, css, angularjs-material

[image]

I used angularjs material tabs here I need scroll for "md-tab-body" section, I have tried all the possibility from stack overflow but not working scroll.

```
<md-tabs md-enable-disconnect md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom md-selected='vm.tabIndex' id="wardName{{$index}}">
  <md-tab ng-repeat="ward in vm.inpatientwards" ng-click="vm.loadWardview(ward._id)">
    <md-tab-label>
      <span translate id="ipwardId{{$index}}">{{ward.name}}</span>
    </md-tab-label>
    <md-tab-body>
      <div style="margin:10px;" layout="row">
        <md-grid-list flex>
          <md-grid-tile ng-repeat="bed in vm.wardbeds" ng-click="vm.selectBed(bed)" id="wardBeds{{$index}}">
            <md-grid-tile-header>
              {{::bed.name}}
            </md-grid-tile-header>
          </md-grid-tile>
        </md-grid-list>
      </div>
    </md-tab-body>
  </md-tab>
</md-tabs>
```

The above code i used my application. I need help to set oveflow-y for body section.

Comment: try to remove md-dynamic-height once

Comment: But i need full height for div, after removed md-dynamic-height the div will display half of the display. I need full height with overflow-y.

Comment: than give md-tabs height: 100%;

Comment: I already tried but still div display half of the page

Comment: you have to give all upper div also same , and md-dynamic-height will auto count the height according to inner content, or else provide codepen or example with this issue.

Comment: sry i don't know where i need to put same height can you take my code show in answer section with correction

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this may this help you in case if your scenario is like this:

```
<!-- if you have any div outside-->
<div style="height:100%"> 
<md-tabs md-enable-disconnect md-border-bottom md-selected='vm.tabIndex' id="wardName{{$index}}" class="helloHeight">
        <md-tab ng-repeat="ward in vm.inpatientwards" ng-click="vm.loadWardview(ward._id)">
            <md-tab-label>
                <span translate id="ipwardId{{$index}}">{{ward.name}}</span>
            </md-tab-label>
            <md-tab-body>
              <!-- try to inspect this div-->
                    <div style="margin:10px;height:100%;overflow-y: auto;" layout="row">
                        <md-grid-list  flex>
                            <md-grid-tile ng-repeat="bed in vm.wardbeds" ng-click="vm.selectBed(bed)" id="wardBeds{{$index}}">
                                <md-grid-tile-header >
                                    {{::bed.name}}
                                </md-grid-tile-header>
                            </md-grid-tile>
                        </md-grid-list>
                </div>
            </md-tab-body>
        </md-tab>
```

```
.helloHeight{
   height:100%;
 }
```

And not sure as not tested this code.

Comment: i have just update my answer adding class to md-tabs and giving that to class height:100% try it once, if you want may it work

Comment: Sry i can't able to access your codepen i didn't see result

Comment: Sry still i can't able to result section. The result section is still loading